# Progressive Web App on iOS: a href opens Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, progressive-web-apps

I am writing a progressive web app. On iOS only, I have the following problem: 
When I refer from one view inside the app to another, safari opens the view.

With a hard coded link like `<a href="start.shtml">Click</a>` this is not happening, but to integrate a flexible navigationbar to every view, I am using shtml and something like this:

```
<a id="link" href="">Click</a>
```

Via javascript I change the target of the link, depending on the current site:

```
if (location.pathname.startsWith("/start.shtml")) {
  document.getElementById("link").href = "/anotherpage.shtml";
}
```

Any ideas why Safari opens the refered site? I am using iOS 10.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Instead of changing the href of the an -tag, I am using a button now to do this via javascript:

```
$("#link").on( "click", function() {
    window.location.href = "anotherpage.shtml";
 });
```